# Specifying multiple "implementation=" tags in @requestbody openapi tag in quarkus REST api

Tags: rest, apache-kafka, openapi, quarkus

I have a quarkus REST api that accepts JSON strings (various kinds) as events and then propagates them to a KAFKA topic.

I want to now put the structure of the possible JSON strings in the openAPI contract (without having to type it out myself manually.

I have managed to find the @requestbody tag that allows me to specify the one structure but I have multiple types of events that all have to go to the same Kafka topic.

example:

```
  @POST
  @Path("/student")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Tag(name = "Student Events Service")
  @Operation(summary = "Accepts student type events", description = "Accepts student type events")
  @APIResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Event sent successfully")
  @APIResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "The JSON packet sent did not conform to any known message or the primary key or shared data in the packet is invalid. \n "
               + "See Response Body for detail. -  "
               + "Error code 400-1 = Bad message structure or unknown message. Log error and continue to next message - "
               + "Error code 400-2 = Bad primary key. Fix data (client or server side) and retry later - "
               + "Error code 400-3 = Invalid shared data. Fix shared data and retry later",
               content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                                  schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)))
  @APIResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Unexpected server error. See Response Body for detail. - "
               + "Error code 500-1 = Unable to send to KAFKA, please wait and retry later - "
               + "Error code 500-2 = Unable to connect to verification database, please wait and retry later - "
               + "Error code 500-3 = General server error, Please wait and retry later",
               content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json",
                                  schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class)))
  public Response postStudentEvent(String eventJSON) {
```

Now I can put the following tag in to generate the openapi contract for 1 class of eventJSON string

```
  @RequestBody(
        required = true,
        content = @Content(
          schema = @Schema(implementation = Application.class)
        )
  )
```

But lets say I also want to be able to accept JSON string with the structure of CourseEnrollment.class (These classes are all part of the project btw).

```
public class CourseEnrollment {

  private String eventID;
  private String eventTime;
  private String eventType;
  private String eventUserSource;
  private String externalReference1;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String emailAddressPrimary;
  private String emailAddressAlternate;
  private String periodStartDate;
  private String periodEndDate;
  private String intakeIntakeYearCode;
  private String programmeCode;

 public class Application   {
  private String eventID;
  private String eventTime;
  private String eventType;
  private String eventUserSource;
  private String eventTrigger;

  
  private ApplicationInfo applicationDetails = null;

  private Person personDetails = null;

  private School schoolDetails = null;
```

Its a wierd scenario I know, but thats what I have to deal with as we have an external system generating the events and sending the JSON to my REST service and I have to propagate the JSON to the KAFKA topics locally.

Thank you for your inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`oneOf`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.2.8/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#oneOf--):

```java
  @RequestBody(
        required = true,
        content = @Content(
          schema = @Schema(oneOf = {Application.class, CourseEnrollment.class})
        )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you SO much. That is precisely wat I was looking for. Worked like a charm